# CoffeeScript function does not seem to be appearing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

```
Ruby 2.1.5
Rails 3.2.18
```

In my CoffeeScript module, I had the following function:

```
disableSelectedOptionsFor = (item)->
  $fields = $(".inventory-table-group:visible")
  $(".#{item} select>option").each (i, el)->
    if el.value != "" && $fields.find("[id$=\"#{el.value}_#{item}_id\"]").length > 0
      $(el).attr('disabled','disabled')
    else
      $(el).removeAttr('disabled')
```

I added the following function:

```
enableAllSelectedOptionsFor = (item)->
  $fields = $(".inventory-table-group:visible")
  $(".#{item} select>option").each (i, el)->
    $(el).removeAttr('disabled')
```

I deleted the /tmp folder. I deleted the /public/assets folder.

I then did:

```
RAILS_ENV=test RAILS_GROUPS=assets bundle exec rake assets:precompile
sudo service apache2 restart
```

I started the Rails app in a Firefox browser. I have firebug installed.

When I look for the `disableSelectedOptionsFor` function, it's there, but I cannot find `enableAllSelectedOptionsFor`.

Any ideas? CoffeeScript is not my strong point.

This is how the disableSelectedOptionFor function appears inside Firebug:

```
disableSelectedOptionsFor = function(item) {
  var $fields;
  $fields = $(".inventory-table-group:visible");
  return $("." + item + " select>option").each(function(i, el) {
    if (el.value !== "" && $fields.find("[id$=\"" + el.value + "_" + item + "_id\"]").length > 0) {
      return $(el).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
      return $(el).removeAttr('disabled');
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: These two functions are in the same file? And are they indented the same? Meaning one isn't "inside" the other?

Comment: They are indented the same, as in one is not inside the other. In the source code, they appear as I have them in my question. Please see the edit to my question